# SAS related to using over and partition proc sql

Tags: sas, proc

Submitted code

```
    proc sql ;
      create table case1 as select 
                             Name, age, height , 
                          AVG(height) OVER (PARTITION BY age) AS avg_ht_age
         from sashelp.class ;
       quit ;
```

SAS Log

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
        
          proc sql ;
           create table case1 as select
                    Name, age, height ,
                   AVG(height) OVER (PARTITION BY age) AS avg_ht_age
                                              ____
                                              22
                                              76
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
               CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  
 
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

I want to get average height for the subjects with same age. I am using this code and it's showing an error.

POV: I know how to deal with using group by.

Comment: `its showing an error` Which error? Post the full error message, alongside the full code and any other thing you deem relevant.

Comment: Hey mate, i have updated the code above please have a look

Comment: Those post ANSI 92 extensions to SQL are not implemented in PROC SQL.  But are not needed for your example since SAS will happily remerge the mean height by age group back onto the detail records for you.

Comment: Hey Tom, I didn.t get what you were trying to say, is it possible to use over and partition in proc SQL in sas studio ?

Comment: No, it is not possible - nor is it needed. Give us an example of your desired result and you will get the answer with code leading to it.

Comment: PROC SQL implements ANSI 92 verison of SQL.   OVER or PARTITION are not defined in that version of the SQL standard.  Your particular example does not need to use these "windowing" functions to get the result you want using PROC SQL.   For more complex calculations just use normal SAS code instead of SQL code to get your results.

Answer (score 3):

PROC SQL does not implement "windowing" operations that OVER and PARTITION BY are part of. It only supports the features of ANSI 92 version of SQL.

SAS does not need these more complex features because (unlike most database systems that implement SQL) it already has a language for manipulating data.

You can use data steps or procs to do more complex data manipulations that SQL cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by statement to group your data.

```
proc sql; 
    create table case1 as 
        select Name, age, height , AVG(height) AS Avg_ht_age 
            from sashelp.class 
            group by age
    ; 
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks Negdo. But i want to try it with using Over and partition.

Comment: Judging by this thread: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Partition-in-Proc-SQL/td-p/748217 you cannot use partition in proc sql. Update your question with code used (not just the error message) and what is your desired result. That way I can update my answer if the result isn't what you want.

Comment: please have a look again Negdo.